# What do I get if my Directrix and Focus are the same?

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

In my calculus class today we had a discussion about whether you'd get a vertical line or just a point when your directrix and focus become the same point. What would happen?

Comment: That sounds like a deep question about mathematics. I highly encourage you to ask it on the Mathematics SE. My initial gut feeling is that the Parabola becomes pointier and pointier as the point and the directrix merge. I suspect : LINE

Comment: A directrix is a *line*, while a focus is a *point*. (Check your definitions again!) How, then, can they be the same?

Comment: J.M., I think the OP intends to ask: what if the focus were to lie on the directrix? That is to say, they share an x- or a y- coordinate

Comment: @Αδριανός, in that case, if the OP can derive the equation of the general conic whose directrix is the $y$-axis, and whose focus is a point on the $x$ axis, he can then study what happens if the movable point becomes the origin.

Comment: Hi John! I tried to ask the question on Mathematics SE but it got redirected to here it would seem. Perhaps I'll try again?

Answer (score 1):

You have everything zoomed out.At the nearest point the distance between focus and directrix is $ d(1+\epsilon)$ where d is distance to focus which when itself shrinks to zero entire scene goes to a point by uniform scaling. If length of feet of a person is 6 inches for his height 6 feet then those of an ant by same proportion would be 6 mm and 0.5  mm respectively.